# Add a non-FK condition to a LEFT OUTER JOIN in Django ORM to return rows that don't join

Tags: python, django, orm, left-join

I want to run a query of the type:

```
SELECT company.id
FROM company
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee
    ON company.id=employee.company_id AND employee.retired=True
WHERE employee.id IS NULL
```

IE, I want the database to try to join each company to an employee where retired=True , and to return me the companies that fail to join.

This will give me all companies who don't have a retired employee, including those with no employees.

Is there any way of doing this in Django without using .raw()?

I can do the LEFT JOIN with `Company.objects.filter(employee__isnull=True)` but I can't add the `retired` join condition, so I get companies with retired employees. I can't make it a `Q()`, because in the `WHERE` clause employee.retired will be NULL. I can do:

```
Company.objects.exclude(id__in=Employee.objects.filter(retired=True).values('company_id'))
```

Which is equivalent to the less efficient:

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT company_id FROM employee WHERE retired=True)
```

Is there a way of achieving the LEFT JOIN in Django?

Or at least changing the second query to a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee WHERE company_id=company.id AND retired=True)` so we're filtering the sub-query?

I'm using Django 1.8.5, postgres 9.4 and psycopg2 2.6.1

Comment: Are you building the database from scratch using django or you are having a legacy database? Because if you are using django, it doesn't make sense to have an employee that has null in `id`. Also, it's better to post your models so we can understand your database a little better.

Comment: Thanks Shang the database was built from scratch with Django, no employee records have a null id - that is just the way I detect that the left join has not managed to find an employee record that satisfies the join criteria. The models are a lot more complex so I created this simplified example to explain my requirement.

Comment: So `Employee` model has a foreignkey to company, right?

Comment: Yes exactly thanks, it has two fields - `company_id` which is the foreign ket to company, and `retired`, the boolean. And both SQL queries, and the Django ORM code, return the same rows: all companies who don't have a retired employee, including companies that have no employees at all. It is just that the first query is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know a better way to achieve this in one shot, because there's no way to tell django to select `ALL` employees are not retired. If you think your query would work, just use `Company.objects.raw()`.

Here's my attempt:

```
no_retired_employees_company = Employee.objects.filter(is_retired=False) \
                                               .values_list('company_id', flat=True).distinct()

no_employee_company = Company.objects.filter(employee__isnull=True) \
                                     .values_list('id', flat=True).distinct()

result = list(a) + list(b)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns companies with a retired employee. I get where you're coming from though - I tried to get the conditions into the `WHERE` clause but it isn't possible.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear about your requirement. Are you trying to return companies that have no retired employees?

Comment: I want all companies who don't have a retired employee, including companies that have no employees at all.

Comment: [This post](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/databases/optimizing-django-db-postgres-queries-left-join/) is the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that creates the same SQL as the example I gave that I'm trying to avoid ie `SELECT * FROM Company WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT company_id FROM Employee WHERE retired=False)`. If Employee is 100K rows+ this becomes much less efficient than the `LEFT JOIN`.